# flatpickr.js disable date range on selection

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I'm using `flatpickr.js` and one of it's events i.e. [onChange](https://flatpickr.js.org/events/#events) to disable a specific range of dates upon selection. Astonishingly when I just pass a specific date to disable, it works but does not when I pass a date range.
Currenly I passing on static dates but once it works, I will make the range dynamic.

```
let picker = document.querySelector("#picker");
let fp = flatpickr(picker, {
        mode: 'range',
        dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
        onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        instance.set('disable', [
                {
                    from: "2019-05-08",
                    to: "2019-04-02"
                }
            ])
        },
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?